# URL Rewrite On .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule which will understand

http://example.com/test/1234

as

http://example.com/test.php?t=1234

This is what I have right now and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test?t=([^/\.]+)/?$ http://mywebsite.com/test/$1 [L]
```

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewriteRule is backwards in that you're supposed to match on the left what you want the clean url to look like and rewrite on the right to where the file is located on the server. But even if it weren't backwards, you'd have to escape the question mark character in the RegExp. But since it is backwards, you should be using something closer to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) test.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test.php\?t=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /test/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/?$ /test.php?t=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Query string is not part of match in rewrite rule directive, Use %{QUERY_STRING} or %{THE_REQUEST} variables to match against the query string.